# Search not searching certain words - how to fix?

Tags: search

I have an entry about the U.K. TV show "Being Human". If I search "being" on the back end, it comes up with 0 results, same on the front end search.

Searching for "Human" brings it up, but "Being Human" does not.

Doe the default "title" field not get indexed by search? How can I enable it if so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to specify the fields you need to search.

```
{% set queryParams = {
        search: {
            query: 'title:*' ~ name ~ '* OR description:*' ~ name ~ '* OR previewText:*' ~ name ~ '* OR tag:*' ~ name ~ '*'
        }
    } %}

{% set entries = craft.entries(queryParams).section('entries').all() %}
```

Comment: Based on your reply, I tried 
`{% set queryParams = { search: { query: 'title:*' ~ searchQuery ~ '* OR mediaDescription:*' ~ searchQuery ~ '*' } } %}
{% set entries = craft.entries(queryParams).search(searchQuery).section('tv, movies, documentaries').orderBy('score').all() %}` but it's still not returning results.

Comment: But this worked...
`{% set queryParams = { search: { query: 'title:*' ~ searchQuery ~ '* OR mediaDescription:*' ~ searchQuery ~ '*' } } %}
{% set entries = craft.entries(queryParams).section('tv, movie, documentaries').orderBy('score').all() %}`

Comment: @MarkD not returning result, because we call method search, when add it in hash queryParams.

Answer (score 1):

"being" is a MyISAM full-text search stopword by default (meaning MySQL will ignore it for full text searches).

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-stopwords.html

If you're on MySQL 5.6+, you can convert Craft's `searchindex` table to InnoDB (where it's not a stopword), or you can edit your MySQL's config stop word list to exclude that word.